# Insert a null Value into a smalldatetime column in SQL using LINQtoSQL via VB?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a smalldatetime column in SQL that can have a null value, but when I try to insert a null value using SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null and LINQtoSQL it puts in 1/1/1900 instead of NULL.

What is the best method to insert a null, or am I doing it at the moment. If I am using the correct method at the moment, what should be done to prevent the 1/1/1900 being displayed on my fields in a WPF application.

The database is SQL 2008.

Thanks

(edit) Code

```
Public Shared Function saveNewClient(ByVal clientName As String, ByVal active As Boolean, ByVal maintRenew As SqlTypes.SqlDateTime, ByVal currOp As Int32) As Int32
Try
    Dim c As New client()
    c.crGUID = Guid.NewGuid
    c.crClientName = clientName
    c.crMaintenanceRenewal = maintRenew
    c.crActive = active
    c.crAddOp = currOp
    c.crAddDate = DateTime.Now
    c.crEditOp = currOp
    c.crEditDate = DateTime.Now

    db.clients.InsertOnSubmit(c)
    db.SubmitChanges()
    Return c.crID
Catch ex As Exception
    Return Nothing
End Try
```

End Function

Comment: Can you post the code that does the actual insert?

Comment: Rippo, Code Added! I didn't think it would help originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use a nullable datatype. Looking at the signature of your function it looks like you are passing in an SqlDateTime for maintRenew.

```
ByVal maintRenew As SqlTypes.SqlDateTime
```

Instead, try passing a nullable DateTime e.g.:

```
ByVal maintRenew As DateTime?
```

Rather than passing in a DBNull, in the calling function you can then pass in a standard "Nothing", (null in (C#), or DateTime as required.

Comment: Hey thanks JamesPickrell, once again you have come through with the solution that has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried null rather than SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null?
Does the database table row show null?

Comment: It needs to be SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null or the LINQ will not insert/update... unless of course it is an actual date. Previously using sprocs I could submit a properly formatted string, ie '20090808 08:00:00' or just String.Empty and it would essentially ignore work as expected. However with LINQtoSQL recognising the datatype it wants something either in the Date format or a proper Sql null.